# Best approach to find matching records in two JSON Files

Tags: java, json, algorithm, jackson, matching

I have two JSON Files- Publishers which has a list of publishers and Books which has a list of books. I have to match the book with the corresponding publisher. The two files are in following formats:

`books.json` (Around 400 books):

```
[{"bookId":"1173828", "bookName":"Dark Sky", "publisher":"ABC", "publisherCountry":"USA"}, ...]
```

`publishers.json` (Around 10 publishers);

```
[{"publisherId":"128", "publisherName":"ABC", "publisherCountry":"USA"}, ...]
```

The output should be of the form:

```
{"results": [{ "bookId": "1173828", "publisherId": 128}, ...]}
```

I am using Jackson JSON to parse the files. I want to know what is the best approach to use for this problem. Should I create individual objects for each record and then compare the objects of Book and Publisher class to find a match?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the *only* problem you have to solve on the data, the fastest approach is to:

1. Parse all publishers, and store the id (or any other additional information you would like to keep for the output) in a hash map, where the publisher name is the key. If you want to match both name and country, you can use a key like `<publisherName>/<publisherCountry>` and it works best if the separator you use naturally doesn't occur in the data. For example `<publisherName>\n<publisherCountry>` as I assume there are on line breaks in these names.
2. Now parse all books, construct the key from the data, e.g. again `<publisher>\n<publisherCountry>`, and look that up in your hash. Now you can output all fields the way you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially doing an *inner join* between books and publishers based on the publisher name.
You can create an index of publishers and books using an associative array (or hashmap). This will associate a unique key (say, the publisher name) to each publisher and books. Once the indexes are created, you can do the inner join between the do by iterating through the keys and merging the data together.

Here is an example implementation in Python:

```py
import json

with open('books.json') as f:
    books = json.load(f)

with open('publishers.json') as f:
    publishers = json.load(f)

books_index = {  # 1
    b['publisher']: {  # 2
        'bookId': b['bookId'],
        'bookName': b['bookName']
    }
    for b in books
}
publishers_index = {
    p['publisherName']: {  # 2
        'publisherId': p['publisherId'],
        'publisherName': p['publisherName'],
        'publisherCountry': p['publisherCountry']
    }
    for p in publishers
}

joined = [
    dict(books_index[k], **publishers_index[k])  # 3
    for k in books_index.keys()
]

results = {
    'results': joined
}
```

Notes :

1. This syntax is called comprehension and you can use it to simply create hashmaps or lists in a single expression. Python's hashmaps are called dicts.
2. This is where you chose the unique key for each book/publisher, and the associated value.
3. This is where you chose how to associate the book with the publisher. Here I just merge the book's and the publisher's dicts into a single one.